# how to inject a service to a predefined controller in angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

i am using angular-ui-router and i have a resolve that brings me some data from the DB by a service.

now i want to inject it into my controller.

but, my controller is not defined in the state, rather just in my application.

this look like this:

```
 .state('myState', {
    url: "/create",
    templateUrl: "views/create.html",
    resolve: { 
        templates : function(templateService){
          return templateService.allMetadata.query({}, function(data){
          }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
          });
        }
    },
    controller: 'createCtrl'
```

so how can i inject my templates into my `createCtrl` which was defined elsewhere.
trying to put a dependency injection my in `createCtrl` didn't work. it seems that the my only option is to decalre my controller inside the `state` decleration. this is obviously very bad.

any solution?

Comment: If templateService.allMetadata.query() is async, then make sure you return a promise from your resolve function.  Then inject 'templates' into your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way or another you need to return a promise for an async operation.  Assuming that templateService.allMetadata.query() is not returning a promise already, try something like this.  Then inject 'templates' into your controller.

If you can modify it to return a promise, do that.

```
 .state('myState', {
    url: "/create",
    templateUrl: "views/create.html",
    resolve: { 
        templates : function(templateService, $q){
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          templateService.allMetadata.query({}, function(data){
              deferred.resolve(data);
          }, function(err){
            console.log(err);
            deferred.reject();
          });
          return deferred.promise;
        }
    },
    controller: 'createCtrl'
```